# Finding the differences of two variables containing strings unix

Tags: unix, diff, sdiff

How i use diff for variables instead of files.

All tutorials have examples with files but not with variables.

I want it to print just the differences.

for example:

```
TEXTA=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz; TEXTB=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyr
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`diff` is a utility to compare two files. If you really want to compare two variables, and you are using `bash` for your shell, you can "fake it" this way:

```
diff <(echo ${TEXTA}) <(echo ${TEXTB})
```

Otherwise, you can just write your variables to two temporary files and compare them.

However, note that in your example, since each variable is a single line, it'll just tell you that they're different, unless you use a version of `diff` that will show you the specific positions in the line where they differ.

Comment: Wa, how does that work? Does bash create temp files on the fly for us? `echo <(echo ${TEXTA})` outputs `/dev/fd/63`, so it seems so. Is it bash magic of is it POSIX?

Comment: It's a `bash` feature - it replaces the `<(command)` with the name of a "file" that appears to contain the output of `command`. It may or may not actually create a file, depending on your platform - in your example it appears to use a pipe instead of actually creating a file. The manual page for `bash` might be an interesting read...

Comment: Ok, the feature is called process substitution. Seems to be a bash extension to POSIX. Nice.

Comment: In the example I just put one difference, but in my thing I'm having more, thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sdiff`.

```
sdiff <(echo $TEXTA) <(echo $TEXTB)
```

`sdiff` points out just the differences between the two strings and shows them side-by-side separated by `|`.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz  | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyr
```

This can be useful when your string is too long. `sdiff` would highlight only the part of the string that is different.